# Can you explain Service-builder concept?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

It's easier to generate tables and default classes with `liferay's service builder`.

But it is bit difficult for me to understand the hierarchy of classes generated by it.

Also the exact use of each class other than modifying `LocalServiceImpl` class as per our need by adding our own functionality.

I have gone through [Service Builder doc](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/service-build-2). So I got some basic knowledge but would like to get more on this.

Even the link "[Liferay Service Builder](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Service+Builder)" was useful but outdated with current Liferay version. So Does anyone have update on above link or nice info explaining hierarchy with example/diagram?.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The [6.1 development guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5) explains the use of relevant classes nicely, and the Wiki link does not seem to be outdated though a few things can be updated. The question seems a bit broad so please try to be more specific so that you can get what you require.

Comment: It might also be interesting to consider *not* using Service Builder. There are some limitations with this framework, such as the absence of foreign keys, the inability of using one-to-one relationships and the fact that relationships are always lazily fetched.

Comment: The concept didn't change in the last versions - did you run into specific outdated pieces of information or are you just talking about the article's age or a mentioned version number?

Answer (score 0):

To implement the foreign key concept in liferay, you have to apply your own coding logic since the implementation of FK are not available in service builder. So I guess you need to put some code.
Read some forums related to service builder on liferay website. It will give you better exposure.
Read Liferay In Action. It is a good book

Answer (score 0):

Here is What I obeserved In Liferay 6.1.

**`com.liferay.portlet.p_name.model`**:

This has interfaces and classes related to (table entity related to) this portlet.

For example `com.liferay.portlet.announcements.model` will have

***Interfaces:***

1. AnnouncementsEntry
2. AnnouncementsEntryModel
3. AnnouncementsDelivery
4. AnnouncementsDeliveryModel
5. AnnouncementsFlag
6. AnnouncementsFlagModel

***Classes:***

And In classes section, You will find wrapper classes and soap classes for each entity like:

1. AnnouncementEntryWrapper
2. AnnouncementEntrySoap
3. AnnouncementFlagWrapper
4. AnnouncementFlagSoap
5. AnnouncementDeliveryWrapper
6. AnnouncementDeliverySoap

Also for few Entity, you will find Classes for Constant entries like
`AnnouncementsEntryConstants`, `AnnouncementsFlagConstants` etc.

**`com.liferay.portlet.p_name.service`**:

This has classes and interfaces related to (table entity related to) this portlet.
For example `com.liferay.portlet.announcements.service` will have

***Interfaces:***

1. AnnouncementsEntryService
2. AnnouncementsEntryLocalService
3. AnnouncementsDeliveryService
4. AnnouncementsDeliveryLocalService
5. AnnouncementsFlagService
6. AnnouncementsFlagLocalService

***Classes:***

And In classes section you will have Util and Wrapper classes.

1. AnnouncementsEntryServiceUtil
2. AnnouncementsEntryServiceWrapper
3. AnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceUtil
4. AnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceWrapper

and so on.....

So In short following is the structure I observed in Liferay

```
[In Model, I:+Model,(ModelName), C:Soap, Wrapper and Constants]

[In Service, I:Service,LocalService ; C:ServiceUtil,ServiceWrapper,LocalServiceUtil and LocalServiceWrapper]

[In Persistence, I:Finder(BlogsEntryFinder),Persistence(BlogsEntryPersistence); C:Util(BlogsEntryUtil, BlogsEntryFinderUtil)]
```

Note:

```
I --> Interface

C --> Class
```